# Sphero Android sample apps not connecting to the robot

Tags: android, sphero-api

Using Android Studio, the recommended IDE for Sphero Android development, I'm trying to run the sample apps that come with the Sphero SDK. I can get them compiling, installing, and debugging on my device (Google Nexus 5). The apps, however, are unable to connect to the Sphero 2.0 robot:

```
12-03 21:37:25.110 6070-6070/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-03 21:37:25.158 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming W/ActivityThread: Application com.orbotix.sensorstreaming is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-03 21:37:25.161 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
12-03 21:37:25.177 6070-6077/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/art: Debugger is active
12-03 21:37:25.362 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: Debugger has connected
12-03 21:37:25.362 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
12-03 21:37:25.562 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
12-03 21:37:25.762 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
12-03 21:37:25.962 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
12-03 21:37:26.163 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
12-03 21:37:26.363 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
12-03 21:37:26.564 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
12-03 21:37:26.764 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/System.out: debugger has settled (1417)
12-03 21:37:26.853 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming-2/lib/arm
12-03 21:37:26.921 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming W/obx-sdk: main    :: Cannot start activity lifecycle monitor: Context used for discovery is not an activity.
12-03 21:37:26.922 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming V/obx-sdk: main    :: BluetoothManager: android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager@72331d9
12-03 21:37:26.922 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming V/obx-sdk: main    :: Bluetooth Adapter: android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter@a02879e
12-03 21:37:26.922 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
12-03 21:37:26.926 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming V/obx-sdk: main    :: Found 0 preconnected devices
12-03 21:37:26.926 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/obx-sdk: main    :: Bluetooth 4.0 Discovery requested: 0 connected 0 visible
12-03 21:37:26.928 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:26.928 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming V/obx-sdk: main    :: DiscoveryAgentClassic.startDiscovery()
12-03 21:37:26.929 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:26.937 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:26.948 6070-6163/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-03 21:37:27.008 6070-6163/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 09/02/15, 76f806e, Ibddc658e36
12-03 21:37:27.011 6070-6163/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-03 21:37:27.941 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:27.942 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:27.943 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:27.944 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:27.947 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:28.954 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:28.955 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:28.957 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:28.959 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:28.963 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:29.968 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:29.969 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:29.970 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:29.971 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:29.972 6070-6082/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:30.975 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:30.979 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:30.992 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:30.999 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:31.008 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:32.032 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:32.036 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:32.043 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:32.048 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:32.058 6070-6082/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:33.078 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:33.079 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:33.080 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:33.081 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:33.082 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:34.086 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:34.092 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:34.099 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:34.104 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:34.113 6070-6082/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:35.133 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:35.133 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:35.135 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:35.135 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:35.138 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:36.141 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:36.145 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:36.153 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:36.157 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:36.167 6070-6082/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:37.190 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:37.194 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:37.209 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:37.213 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:37.240 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:38.252 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:38.255 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:38.268 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:38.271 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:38.281 6070-6082/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:39.307 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:39.308 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:39.311 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:39.312 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:39.315 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:39.783 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming W/obx-sdk: main    :: Discovery finished, restarting as nothing was found
12-03 21:37:40.327 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:40.328 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:40.329 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:40.330 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:40.331 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:41.334 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:41.338 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:41.345 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:41.357 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:41.372 6070-6082/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:42.377 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:42.382 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:42.389 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:42.394 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:42.404 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:43.428 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:43.432 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:43.439 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:43.443 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:43.453 6070-6082/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:44.475 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:44.477 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:44.481 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-03 21:37:44.483 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:44.489 6070-6083/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-03 21:37:44.944 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming V/obx-sdk: main    :: Interrupted discovery runnable
12-03 21:37:44.944 6070-6070/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming V/obx-sdk: main    :: DiscoveryAgentClassic.stopDiscovery()
12-03 21:37:45.007 6070-6163/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9426de0
12-03 21:37:45.499 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-03 21:37:45.501 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
12-03 21:37:45.502 6070-6161/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming V/obx-sdk: Thread-5051     :: Discovery runnable no longer running
```

The app did come with the appropriate permissions pre-set in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

I have paired the phone with the robot and the official Sphero app connects immediately. What am I missing?

EDIT: I've tried the sample apps for both Android Studio and Unity now and neither can connect. The official app continues to function properly. I wish Orbotix would release *that* code.

Comment: Have you tried the sample app without the debugger?

Comment: Are you making sure that you're not missing to make any network related calls in your code.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Same result.

I'm concerned about this line in the log:

    12-04 20:24:26.889 30805-30805/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.orbotix.sensorstreaming-1/lib/arm

Comment: @zulkarnain I'm running the sample code as provided with the SDK. If there are calls missing, they were shipped that way.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson And if you are running/building on 6.0 you've got the permissions handling correct? https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK/issues/16

Comment: @MorrisonChang D'oh. I missed that thread. This was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphero Android developer here.

Since those samples target API 22 (At least for now. I have it on my to-do list to update to 23 and add permission support examples), you won't need to worry about requesting permissions at runtime. However, since you're using a Nexus 5, I'm going to guess you're on Marshmallow. With the latest Android OS, location permissions are necessary to scan and connect to Bluetooth. Try adding the following line to your permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Also you will need to make sure that your device level Location Services are enabled.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much. This would be a great addition to the documentation/SDK. ;)